# WordPress editor templates

Tags: wordpress, templates, wysiwyg, multiple-columns

I have a responsive layout and need a solution for editors to easily create muti-column content within TincyMCE.

Found some Plugins which allow me to create simple Templates/Snippets which can be inserted into Tiny and then modified (e. g. [TinMCE Templates](http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-templates/)).
I don´t like the solution for some reasons. Editors could (and will) break things badly by accidently removing tags or nesting things. Moreover there seems to be no way to leave the parent div.

I think the best solution would be a button which opens a dialog, where editors can select a layout/style and then fill out predefined fields. For example: Click button, choose layout "2 columns", a form appears with fields for column 1 and column 2 (title and body). I appended a mockup for clarification.

If the editor inserts a template and wants to edit the texts, ideally he just clicks a part of the inserted template and the overlay opens again, so that nothing gets broken.

Is there such a plugin? Or an other built-in way?

[image: Insert templates mockup]

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72394/how-to-add-a-shortcode-button-to-the-tinymce-editor

here is a solution for that, this should work for you

Comment: That would work if I wanted to insert a shortcode via a button. But i don´t think that this is related to my question in any way?

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin that you're looking for to achieve multi-column support → [Easy Columns](http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-columns/)

Comment: Don´t really like this solution with shortcodes. Maybe i´m too ambitious. But I want a rock-solid, super user-friendly solution where it´s not enough to accidently remove a single bracket to destroy the whole layout. Maybe I have to write a plugin of my own.